# Banking security service isn't running

Tags: services

## Background

In Korea, they require specific software to be run on your system when logged into banking services. I am still new to Ubuntu, but I am trying to get the required service running, but it seems to not be working.

## Issue

The banking website allows for a simple button-click install of all needed software. However, one piece called `IPinside` requires me to manually start the service I guess.

[image: IP inside software requires start]

However, when I click on `Start IPinside`, nothing happens! I can click on the button multiple times with absolutely nothing for a response.

## What I Tried

So I checked `systemctl` and got the following results.

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files --type service -all

UNIT FILE                                  STATE          
...
ipinside-lws.service                       generated      
IPinsided-LWS.service                      generated
```

I don't know what `generated` means in this context, and I don't know why there are 2 services. So I checked their status. FYI, they both show green dots.

```
$ systemctl status ipinside-lws.service

● ipinside-lws.service - LSB: Interezen IPinsided-LWS
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ipinside-lws; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-05-08 13:51:45 KST; 1h 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ipinside-lws.service
           └─12875 LWSDaemon

May 08 13:51:44 Lenovo systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Interezen IPinsided-LWS...
May 08 13:51:45 Lenovo systemd[1]: Started LSB: Interezen IPinsided-LWS.
```

```
$ systemctl status IPinsided-LWS.service

● ipinside-lws.service - LSB: Interezen IPinsided-LWS
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ipinside-lws; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-05-08 13:51:45 KST; 1h 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ipinside-lws.service
           └─12875 LWSDaemon

May 08 13:51:44 Lenovo systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Interezen IPinsided-LWS...
May 08 13:51:45 Lenovo systemd[1]: Started LSB: Interezen IPinsided-LWS.
```

I also tried to `enable`, `start`, and `restart` both services; however, the website still expresses issues. The website tells me the software is installed, but I get the following dialog response...

```
Module for electronic transaction fraud prevention service is either not installed or
not run properly.
```

Comment: You may have started it multiple times by continuing to click the "Start IPinside" button. You're only supposed to click it once, then click the "Close" button. Reboot your system and see if it works. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema what kind of UX is that? Anyways, I restarted, ran `systemctl list-unit-files --type service -all` and `systemctl status ipinside-lws.service` again, and I got the same output. Also, the webpage still shows the same dialog message. It is installed correctly based on another part of the website.

Comment: I don't know what UX is. Does the software require you to open ports in the firewall? Are proxies enabled? What OS? What version?

Comment: User eXperience ... its similar to UI. As for the ports, I assume not. It should be a one-click install and use experience. The webpage is https://www.kebhana.com/easyone_index_en.html# . Just click on Login on the top and see the process (you will be auto directed to the installation webpage). After installed it should not redirect you back to the installation webpage when you go back

Comment: You probably downloaded/installed the "integrated" installation program. Download the three separate downloads (the last two will probably fix this) and install those, reboot, then retry.

Comment: all 3 show they are installed. Also, I manually reinstalled the last one (IPinside) before. However, installation doesn't seem to be an issue. I'm stuck on the "next" step technically

Comment: Contact Support at the Bank.

Comment: Yeah, I sent a message to their FB page for expats. They helped me with another issue before. But I will try via phone asap. Its Friday night (midnight) and just trying my luck at understanding the issue more. I have no idea what the issue is. IPinside, website, or Chrome. Firefox doesn't do the redirecting, but it tells me to install software I already have installed. Manualy installation says I have it installed already, but can't move forward